# Moving values from one array to another in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have tried doing this for a while and can't wrap my head around it. I have two arrays. One array that contains sensors information called `$sendatas` and another that contains where those sensors are allocated to called `$zones`.

I want to be able to create dynamic HTML checkboxes within a table row based on whether the sensor is allocated to a zone or not and if it is then show a checked checkbox and if it isn't then show an unchecked checkbox.

Here is an example of my arrays:

The `$sendatas` array:

```
  [1] => Array
    (
        [hwserial] => 00002025
        [name] => FG05 Room Temp
        [serial] => 5
        [chan] => 1
        [alarmhigh] => 30
        [alarmlow] => 5
        [delay] => 10
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [hwserial] => 00002025 01
        [name] => FG05 Kitchen 1 Freezer
        [serial] => 5
        [chan] => 2
        [alarmhigh] => -10
        [alarmlow] => -35
        [delay] => 10
    )
```

The `$zones` array:

```
 [0] => Array
    (
        [serial] => 1
        [idGrid] => 50
        [name] => All Sensors
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [serial] => 1
        [idGrid] => 52
        [name] => Food Area
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [serial] => 2
        [idGrid] => 50
        [name] => All Sensors
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [serial] => 2
        [idGrid] => 52
        [name] => Food Area
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [serial] => 3
        [idGrid] => 50
        [name] => All Sensors
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [serial] => 3
        [idGrid] => 52
        [name] => Food Area
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [serial] => 4
        [idGrid] => 50
        [name] => All Sensors
    )
```

Both of my zones are not the same length. What I want to be able to achieve is to create an array that looks like this by finding the serial keys that match from both arrays.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [hwserial] => 00001216
        [name] => Fridge Office Thermal 
        [serial] => 1
        [chan] => 1
        [alarmhigh] => 8
        [alarmlow] => -2
        [delay] => 10
        [idGrid1] => 50
        [idGrid2] => 51
        [idGrid3] => 52
        [zonename1] => All Sensors
        [zonename2] => Office
        [zonename3] => Food Area
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [hwserial] => 00002025
        [name] => FG05 Room Temp
        [serial] => 5
        [chan] => 1
        [alarmhigh] => 30
        [alarmlow] => 5
        [delay] => 10
        [idGrid] => 50
        [idGrid] => Not Used
        [idGrid] => 52
        [zonename1] => All Sensors
        [zonename2] => Not Used
        [zonename3] => Food Area

    )
```

I am pretty sure I can write the code for the checkboxes once I have this array formatted properly. I have tried using some foreach loops but just keep making a mess of it. I have so far tried this on and off for a few weeks hoping it would just come to me but it hasn't. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Adding the code you've tried is suggested in asking questions.

Comment: I've tried figuring it out but couldn't... By what key should we know where the zones go?

Comment: The key of "serial" is the key I wish to use to match them both with. I will try and find the code I have already tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you said you're trying to do with this, I think it looks like the array you're trying to create will not be that easy to work with. I think your sensors array is fine, and you just need to focus on the `$zones` array.

```
foreach ($zones as $zone) {
    $zones_sensors[$zone['idGrid']]['name'] = $zone['name'];
    $zones_sensors[$zone['idGrid']]['sensors'][$zone['serial']] = true;
}
```

This will reorganize the data in your `$zones` array into this format:

```
$zones_sensors = [
    50 => ['name' => 'All Sensors', 'sensors' => [1 => true, 2 => true, 3 => true]],
    51 => ['name' => 'Office', 'sensors' => [1 => true]],
    52 => ['name' => 'Food Area', 'sensors' => [1 => true, 2 => true, 3 => true]]
];
```

This provides the two things you need to output the checkboxes as you described.

1. A complete list of zones
2. An indexed collection of serials associated with each zone.

You can use it to output headers for all the zones

```
foreach ($zones_sensors as $zone_id => $zone) {
    // output one row with headers for zones
    echo $zone['name'];  // (formatting up to you)
}
```

Then when you output the sensors it will be easy to find which zones they're allocated to.

```
foreach ($sendatas as $sensor) {                       // make a row for each sensor

    foreach ($zones_sensors as $zone_id => $zone) {    // iterate the full list of zones
        // check if the sensor is allocated to that zone
        if (isset($zone['sensors'][$sensor['serial']])) {
            // checkbox is checked
        } else {
            // checkbox is unchecked
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should just be a matter of creating a new array (let's call it $combined) that is a clone of one of the $sendatas array but uses the [serial] as a key so that you can target specific item. You would loop through the $zones array and for each item check if the [serial] is found in $combo and if a match is found inject the [idgrid] and [name] as a sub array for $combined['serial']. As you have not used sub array you could add a counter to add an incrementing number of values.

Answer (score -1):

Something along the lines of this should do the trick:

```
$results = [];

foreach ($sendatas as $sensor) {
    $zone_counter = 0;

    foreach ($zones as $zone) {
        if ($zone['serial'] == $sensor['serial']) {
            $zone_counter++;

            $sensor['idGrid' . $zone_counter] = $zone['idGrid'];
            $sensor['zonename' . $zone_counter] = $zone['name'];
        }
    }

    $results[] = $sensor;

    // if you only want $results to contain sensors that actually have zones,
    // wrap it in an if-statement:
    // if ($zone_counter > 0) {
    //     $results[] = $sensor;
    // }
}

print_r($results);
```

Note that this won't give you any sensors with matching zones with the data you provided, because those two sensors both have `[serial] => 5` and all your zones have `[serial] => 1` through `4`. If you want to match by some other key instead of serial, just change the if-statement.